# Github OAuth with Jenkins for organisation

Tags: jenkins, github, oauth

I was reading this https://medium.com/@vsreelasya/github-oauth-for-jenkins-d21d76a3ff09
It is pretty straight forward.

There are a few points I have to clear:

- in my case, in the context of **organization**, should I create a separate account for Jenkins?
- if no separate account is needed there is  / settings / OAuth App where I can fill almost the same things as in the tutorial

In Jenkins seems there are a lot of places where I can insert credentials:

- in "Configure Global Security" > "Github Authentication Plugin" > "Global GitHub OAuth Settings"
- in "Configure system" > "Github"
- in the job "Source Code Management" > "Git" > "Repositories"

Do I have to add the credentials to all of those places?

Answer (score 0):

Github OAuth lets Jenkins depend on Github as an identity provider. Users will use Github to log into Jenkins. No extra "Jenkins" account is necessary on Github. You may set up Github OAuth in "Configure Global Security" > "Authentication" > "Security Realm" > "Github Authentication Plugin" as per [this how-to](https://github.com/cloudposse/jenkins/blob/master/docs/github-oauth2.md). Just make sure you adjust the system authorization so you won't end up losing admin access to Jenkins.

"Configure system" > "Github" lets you manage the Github endpoints your Jenkins jobs may use for SCM checkout. You may add the public Github API or an on-premise Github Enterprise installation. It has nothing to do with Github OAuth.

I presume "Source Code Management" > "Git" > "Repositories" is a job configuration, but it definitely has nothing to do with Github OAuth.